# How does Transcendence scale? (The monk passive: spirit spent heals you)

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-monk

The amount of health per point is going up but I'm now sure what determines it

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why are numbers in skill descriptions green?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66146/why-are-numbers-in-skill-descriptions-green)

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate at all, although the answers are related.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All of the monk's healing abilities scale up with *level*, and not with a specific stat at all. This includes Breath of Heaven and Mantra of Healing as well.

You can also get that same "Healing from spirit spent" on certain magical Spiritstones, Daibos, and Fist Weapons.